# Cannot figure out how to write a formula as input

Tags: input

I am trying to re-write some equation as input in Mathematica, but still cannot get it correctly.

Comment: Where is `i`(your summation index) in the TeX formula?

Comment: You'll need to define n.  You don/t need both `Table` and `Total`, because `Sum` combines those.  What is `j`?  Specify yourself an intermediate variable `mu43 = ...` to simplify your code.  Use whitespace to clarify your code.

Comment: @belisarius, thanks, you were right. Even the TeX formula was wrongly. Sorry for that. It should be OK now. I also defined "mu" separately, but it is used only once so I thought there was no need to define that, but it look clearer now :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
f[r_, t_, n_] := With[{m = (2^(2/3)*(Gamma[7/6]/Gamma[1/2]))^(-3)},
(m n^2 )/(n - 4)Sum
  [Times @@ (Abs[#]^(4/3) & /@ {r[[t, j - 4]], r[[t, j - 2]],r[[t, j]]}),
  {j, 5, n}]]
```

Testing on rectangular array:

```
r = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 10}];
r // MatrixForm
f[r, #, 5] & /@ Range[5]
```

[image]

Ragged array:

```
test = Join@Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, j], {j, 5, 10}]
MapThread[f[test, #1, Length[#2]] &, {Range[Length[test]], test}]
```

[image]

Please check with your own test sample achieves desired result.

Comment: `Total[Table[...]] == Sum[...]`

Comment: @belisarius will edit...not well...missing point a little too much lately

Comment: Trying to shorten it:`f1[r_, t_, n_] :=  With[{m = 1/4 (Gamma[7/6]/Sqrt@Pi)^-3}, 
  m n^2/(n - 4) Sum[    Times @@ Abs@r[[t, j - 4 ;; j ;; 2]]^(4/3), {j, 5, n}]]`